# Zend Bootstrap Action Helper Discrepency

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have the following code in bootstrap.php

```
    Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPath(
        APPLICATION_PATH . '/controllers/actions/helpers',
        'Default_Controller_Action_Helper'
    );
```

And the Action Helpers in that directory are prefixed with: **Default_Controller_Action_Helper_**

**My question is:** How come everything works the same way when I add an underscore at the end of Default_Controller_Action_Helper prefix in bootstrap.php?  Nothing changes with or without the underscore at the end of the prefix in bootstrap.php

This code works the same way as the one above without me changing anything else:

```
    Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPath(
        APPLICATION_PATH . '/controllers/actions/helpers',
        'Default_Controller_Action_Helper_'
    );
```

Any known explanations to this behavior at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you work your way through the code starting in Zend/Controller/Action/HelperBroker.php and look at addpath() that will eventually lead you to Zend/Loader/PluginLoader.php and _formatPrefix().

You will see the last line of this function is `return rtrim($prefix, '_') . '_';` , so your '_' character is being stripped if it is there and then added again to deal with cases where it is omitted, hence the behaviour you are seeing.

In order to really learn ZF you have to get into the code and work out what is actually happening.

Answer (score 0):

```
$x = rtrim($x, '_') . '_';
```

This is a common way to normalize parameters. Another example

```
$x = substr($x, -1) == '_' ? substr($x, 0, -1) : $x;
```

There are probably much more ways to normalize values